# Batch file to generate WinSCP command to get all files between a certain date and time

Tags: scripting, wildcard, winscp

I have a batch file that creates a script file run from WinSCP:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P password="Enter root password: "

ECHO. 
cd HSBC

SET /P dt="Enter DATE (yyyy-mm-dd) : "

ECHO option batch abort>>myscript.txt
ECHO option confirm off>>myscript.txt
ECHO open %password%>>myscript.txt
ECHO cd /jbc/T24/UKMPE/bnk/bnk.data/eb/"&HOLD&">>myscript.txt
ECHO get * >%dt% 07:00:00, <%dt%08:00:00>>myscript.txt
ECHO exit>>myscript.txt

c:\"program files"\winscp\winscp.com /script=myscript.txt

del myscript.txt

ECHO.
ECHO.
```

Problem is line containing `ECHO get * >%dt% 07:00:00, <%dt%08:00:00>>myscript.txt`

It should be a command to get all files between a certain date and time.

If anyone can re-write line to get all files between a certain date and time it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not really specify, what is the problem, you are facing. So can only guess, the problem is, that you have wrong syntax in:

- [WinSCP file mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time): There should be no comma between "after" and "before" constraints.
  The mask should be like:
  `* >2014-09-22 07:00:00 <2014-09-22 08:00`
  (note that the spaces before `>` and `<` are optional)
- [WinSCP `get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get): The mask, containing spaces, has to be enclosed in double quotes, so that is it interpreted as one mask:
  `get "* >2014-09-22 07:00:00 <2014-09-22 08:00"`
- Windows `echo` command: The `>` and `<` are interpreted as input output redirection. What actually gets resolved by the double quotes above. Were not there any double-quotes, you can escape them using the `^`.

Complete command is:

```
ECHO get "* >%dt% 07:00:00 <%dt% 08:00:00" >>myscript.txt
```

---

Side note: The `open %password%` does not look right either. The [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) takes a [session URL](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/session_url) as an argument, not just a password.